# Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab

I tried to make a function that generates a number of strings.

```
function [p] = GetPattern (v)
load('code128B.mat')

for a=1:length(code128B)
    if v == code128B(a,1)
        p=code128B{a,3};
    end
end
```

code128B.mat contains data, first column are numbers while third column are strings. I want to input numbers and produce a string.
why this function produce an error: Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.? I don't get it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: there is something wrong with your code-> code128B is not defined!; probably code128B = load(...) should do it :)

Comment: You need to use `code128B{a,1}` instead of `code128B(a,1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For cell arrays, curly braces (`{}`) are used to extract the contents of the cells, while  parentheses (`()`) are used to extract a subset of the cells (that is, the result is also a cell array).

Use `code128B{a,1}` instead of `code128B(a,1)` to get the number instead of a cell containing the number. However, if `v` is also a cell then you have to use `isequal` to compare their contents.